# Добавление к имени даты, при загрузке изображений

Tags: ajax, php

есть обработчик ajax запроса

```
<?php

$uploaddir = './uploads/'; 
$date=time();
$file = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 
$ext = substr($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'],strpos($date.$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'],'.'),strlen($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'])-1); 
$filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png','.JPG','.BMP','.GIF','.PNG','.jpeg','.JPEG');
if(!in_array($ext,$filetypes)){
    echo "<div class='act_error'><p>Данный формат файлов не поддерживается</p></div>";
}
else{  
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 
    echo "success"; 
    } 
    else {
        echo "error";
    }
}
?>
```

как реализовать так, что-бы при загрузке изображения  к имени изображения добавлялась дата загрузки?
Пример: загружаем изображение - images.jpg, дата загрузки - 011213, на выходе получаем - 011213images.jpg, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Наверно вы это имеете в виду:

```
$file = $uploaddir.date("dmy").basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
```

Comment: так логично, но изображение не загружаются вообще!

Comment: вот ссылка на скрипт index.php
http://javascript.ru/forum/dom-window/41473-zagruzka-izobrazhenijj.html